# CSS3 gradient not scrolling properly

Tags: css, gradient

Here is my site here: [Link](http://www.leemangas.com)

I've looked around for a bit but couldn't find what I was looking for.
I'm attempting to use CSS gradient for my website background but it is not resizing properly.  Instead it will repeat itself when you have to scroll.  Even with background-repeat set to no repeat, I am still having this problem.  Anyone know what my problem is?  Here is my css.

```
html{
height:100%;
}
body {font: 14px/normal Tahoma, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
height: 100%;
min-height:100%;
margin:0;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-attachment:fixed;

background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#000), to(#ccc)); 

  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #000, #ccc);

  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #000, #ccc);

  background-image: linear-gradient(top, #000, #ccc);  

}
```

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer that most helped you! (clicking the 'V' mark ) ... that's the way we say 'Thanks' here.

Comment: Turns out the twitter feed at the bottom of the page loads (therefore lengthening the page) after the CSS code and the CSS code has trouble maintaining the gradient afterwards.  Still no idea how to fix though.

Answer (score 8):

The `background-attachment:fixed` do what you want, but next you are setting `background:` and overwriting that value. Replace it with `background-image` and you are done.

Comment: Sorry for that slight error, but that is not fixing my problems.  Everytime I need to scroll, it is still repeating my gradient.  Still no progress =/

Answer (score 5):

```
background:url(/_pix/bg.png) repeat,-webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,color-stop(0,#C8AA86),color-stop(1,#664927));
background:url(/_pix/bg.png) repeat,-webkit-linear-gradient(top,#C8AA86 0%,#664927 100%);
background:url(/_pix/bg.png) repeat,-moz-linear-gradient(top,#C8AA86 0%,#664927 100%);
background:url(/_pix/bg.png) repeat,-ms-linear-gradient(top,#C8AA86 0%,#664927 100%);
background:url(/_pix/bg.png) repeat,-o-linear-gradient(top,#C8AA86 0%,#664927 100%);
background:url(/_pix/bg.png) repeat,linear-gradient(top,#C8AA86 0%,#664927 100%);
background-attachment:fixed;
```

Answer (score 2):

Just set background-color to #ccc and the problem should go away. The rest of your page will simply be #ccc. It's a limitation of gradients + `background-size`. In theory, `background-size:cover` should fix this correctly, but it doesn't seem to do so because of the interaction of the various specs.

`background-attachment:fixed` actually fixes the background so it never scrolls, which solves the problem, but adds that visual artifact.

Comment: I've tried background-attachment:fixed but it seems to not help my situation.

Comment: I suggested *not* using that. Did you try the other solution? eg, `background-color:#ccc;`?

Answer (score 2):

You need to do in order

```
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#000), to(#ccc)); 
    background-attachment:fixed;
```

That should work